# Publish.NET WCF Service to Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, publish

I have a project with the following structure:

Console Application

- Console Application (Handles entities and db)
- WCF Application

It works when i deploy it on localhost, but i want to publish it on azurewebsites.net.

I've created a free account and downloaded the publish profile. Using this profile, i tried to publish my project, when i get following errors.

Error   2   The 'Connection String' argument cannot be null or empty.       0   0

Error   3   Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete an operation with the specified provider ("dbDacFx") when connecting using the Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized the user for this operation. dbDacFx http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DEPLOYMENTPROVIDER.).

Comment: did you ever determine a solution to this problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Solution with one Web Site Project and multiple Web Job Projects.  I get this error when I attempt to publish any of my Web Jobs to Azure.  The problem is somehow caused when I do a `Build All` on my solution or a `Build` on a single Web Job Project before I try to `Publish` that Project.

The resolution: 
As long as I right-click my project and do a `Clean` and then immediately run a `Publish as Azure Webjob...` my project will publish properly.